# Pattern in Weight of evidence and Information Value approach

Tags: regression, logistic, information-theory

I am trying to build a logistic regression Model and for that I am following Weight of evidence and Information Value approach to assess the predictive power of the variables. I have tried the "Information Package" but I couldn't find the Pattern in the same. I am following the Book "Developing and Implementing Intelligent Credit Scoring" authored by Naeem Siddiqi in which he has also mentioned the Pattern in Weight of Evidence. How to get the pattern in Weight of Evidence?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "pattern" in weight of evidence ?
If you are talking about the woe distribution you can use the **plot_infotables** function from the **Information package** after computing the Information value table

For exmple:

```
IV <- create_infotables(data=mydata, y="target_name", bins=10)
plot_infotables(IV, "myVarname")
```

if you want to have more control or don't want a ggplot you can take the output directly from the table, with something like that, with one variable

```
barplot(IV$Tables[[1]]$WOE, names.arg=IV$Tables[[1]][[1]],
        main="Weight of Evidence", las=2)
```